# Where to find adb_usb.ini in Linux machine

Tags: android, linux, usb, adb, android-usb

I want to make some modifications to my adb_usb.ini to detect android device how ever I could not find the same in Linux machine(Ubuntu OS). I can able to find in Windows machine under C:\Users\.android\adb_usb.ini How ever I could n't find same file in Linux machine. It would be great if I could locate same file in Ubuntu also. If not is there any file equivalent to adb_usb.ini file in Linux?  I did search for file and folder with same name, how ever I could not find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On "unix" (Linux/OSX) platforms for android development, this will be in the .android subdirectory of your home directory.

However beware that on Linux, you also typically need to grant permission to the USB device node using a udev rule or similar matching the VID or VID/PID combination.  And you must restart udev or tell it to reload the rules after changing them.

Comment: Cool Thanks, I found .android folder under /home/<username>/.android/adb-usb.ini

Comment: Link to list of vendor IDs for Unix/Linux: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds

Comment: Yes, that matches the home directory location most Linux distros seem to be using at present, but it should not be assumed universally valid.  What matters is that it's the .android subdirectory of whatever the user's home directory actually is.